# PHP: can't insert data to database in web hosting, but in local it's working using CI

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm writing PHP using CI. I inserted data, but got an error like this:

[image]

Code:

```php
class Recruit extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Resume_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->data['posts'] = $this->Resume_model->get_resume();
        $this->load->view('recruit', $this->data);
    }

    public function resume_form() {
        echo 'OK';
        $test = $this->input->post('type');
        echo 'test:',$test;
        echo 'KO';
        $save = array(
            'type' =>$this->input->post('type'),
            'fullname' =>$this->input->post('fullname'),
            'tel' =>$this->input->post('tel'),
            'location' =>$this->input->post('location')
        );
        $this->Resume_model->saveResume($save);
        redirect(base_url()."recruit");
    }

Class Resume_model extends CI_Model {
    function saveResume($data) {
        {
            $this->db->insert('resume', $data);
            $resume_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        return $resume_id;
    }

    function get_resume() {
        $this->db->select("fullname,type"); 
        $this->db->from('resume');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function getResume() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM resume'); 
        if($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    public function deleteResume($id) {
        $this -> db -> where('id', $id);
        $this -> db -> delete('resume');
    }
```

[image]

Comment: it means that the post vars in the save array are empty when they cannot be. in `resume_form` you can `print_r($_POST)` to see what post vars are posted.

Comment: well it means you are inserting `null` into a field that is not Nullable.  In some versions of MySQL this is an error, in others not so much.  Just like VARCAR size etc...

Comment: For this you have to make your column in database by assigning null then it will allow you to insert data even if your variable is empty.

Comment: Check, the datatype of the "type" column. Might be it's "Int" and you are inserting the string. I think you have to use 1 for true and 0 for false value in the radio button.

Comment: This is not related to web hosting, try to debug by creating a hard coded array like `$save = array(
            'type' =>1,
            'fullname' =>'sam',
            'tel' =>'435436443',
            'location' =>'dubai'
        );`
and pass it to the model if it is working fine then you have to debug the post values.

Comment: You should use CI's `form_validation`. Always. User input is never to be trusted. That said, a `var_dump` or a `print_r` of the `$_POST` superglobal shows what?

Comment: I'm change $save to $save = array( 'type' =>1, 'fullname' =>'sam', 'tel' =>'435436443', 'location' =>'dubai' ); is working then I print_r($_POST) result is Array() I think the problem from post method how to fix it???

Comment: I'm already fix this issue. the problem because of .htaccess file I'm fix this file then post method is working. thank every one.

Answer (score 0):

Make your fields in the DB to allow NULL input.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is simple, your localhost environment and your online environment are different. Different MySQL configurations or different versions causes these errors.

Sometimes there is a need for putting in an empty record into a reference table for future use or because of the order of your coding event but to fix it you have to either put data into your columns upon inserting or setting your column (`type`) to 'NULL' or 'NULLABLE' from the DB.

Comment: This is not a MySQL issue. The data to be inserted is missing before getting to the insertion

Comment: @JavierLarroulet there is no need for a downvote what I have said is perfectly valid. if the fact that whatever he is doing in localhost is not giving him an issue but what he is doing online is producing an error. It is obvious there is an environment difference. If you read the latter part of what I wrote, I mention that he needs to make his fields Null.